# Adding Torque To Character With FixedAngle 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

I've been stuck on this the last few days so I'm hoping you guys can help.

I'm making a 2D game and I want my character to slip, fall backwards, and hit his head when he tries to run on ice for too long.
My goal is to have it where if you keep holding the run button long enough on ice, he will slip backwards and damage himself.
I'm using playmaker but I do know a little c# programming.

The first thing I tried was making an animated float that adds the rotation to the Z axis over time, but that went horribly wrong and makes the character jump/skip/glitch all over the place.

The second thing I thought of was to add 2D torque to make him start slipping backwards, but he stays in the same rotation with fixedAngle true.

So then I made it where fixedAngle is false when he is on ice, but he immediately falls forward or backwards as soon as I start running. I made the center of mass right in the middle so he stands fine as long as he is not moving.

Does anybody know a way of achieving the effect I want?
This is my first game and I am a noob, so hopefully there is an easier/correct way of going about this. I could be doing this all wrong, so any guide in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question does not make sense to me.  If a character starts running forward on ice, the character does not slide backwards but rather moves forward at a slower pace.  Why would the character slide backwards?

Comment: He doesn't slide backwards. He rotates backwards like if you stepped on ice and and your feet went out from under you, and you fall backwards and hit your head.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like from your verbage, you want to be tracking the amount of time the player has been running on ice.

If you want to tie this to the run key being down, start the timer if the button is down and trigger the "slip-and-fall" event to occur after a certain amount of time.

If you want to tie this to the amount of time the player has been on the ice, start the timer when the player reaches the ice and trigger the "slip-and-fall" event to occur after a certain amount of time.

If you want there to be a visual tilting, tie the time delta to the angle of the object. Set a certain angle to trigger the "slip-and-fall" event.

```
Update(){
    if(this.running && _terrainAtPos == <Ice> && isGrounded){
        transform.Rotate(0,0,3*Time.deltaTime);
        if(tranform.rotation.z > 180){
            //do falling event
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: The above is not a working sample. Just something I whipped up to illustrate.